# overriding method read in trait Reads.

Tags: json, scala

I'm implementig this User.scala class

```
class User(var id : Long , var name : String) {

 def createUser() = {}

 def setName(nome : String) : String = {
    this.name = nome
    return name
 }

 def getName() : String = {
    return name
 }
}

object User {

implicit object userFormat extends Format[User] {

  override def reads(json: JsValue): User = new 
  User(

      (json \ "id").as[Long],

      (json \ "name").as[String]

  )

   override def writes(s: User): JsValue = JsObject(Seq(
        "id" -> JsString(s.id.toString),
        "name" -> JsString(s.name)
    ))   
  }
}
```

But I get this Error when on reads method: 
overriding method reads in trait Reads of type (json:play.api.libs.json.JsValue)play.api.libs.json.JsResult[models.User];
method reads has incompatible type

I don't want to use a case class (or the problem would be solved),
Can anybody give me an Hint on what to do?

Thanks.

Comment: As the signature suggests, the method should return `JsResult[T]` and you're returning bare `T`... At least that's what I can tell at the first glance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should wrap the "User" object in a JsResult, in this case [JsSuccess](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/2.1-RC3/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/json/JsResult.scala#L6)

```
JsSuccess(new User(...))
```

Comment: Thanks, I tryed your solution, but when I run the test it gieves me an error at [error] models.User$userFormat$.reads(User.scala:50)
[error] models.User$userFormat$.reads(User.scala:43), that is where I wrapped the "User" object.

Comment: Sorry, your solution is good. There was a stupid error that I just fixed. Thank you very much. I don't know why I did't tryed to wrapped it with JsSuccess.

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.